# how multiple parenthesis after function name work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I am learning javascript, specifically react-js.

[Here](https://github.com/jackielii/simplest-redux-example/blob/master/index.js) is a simplest example I am following to learn these technologies.

What I have learnt that usually we call a function like this

```
function_name (param1, param2) {
}
```

but I can't understand how multiple parenthesis after function name work.  (atleast for a beginner like me).

I couldn't google anything as I don't know what do we call this kind of syntax in javascript.

```
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';

class Counter extends Component {

const App = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Counter)      

}                                                         ^(this)?
```

In the above example,  How do they work?

Comment: Specifically, to _call_ a function we do it like this: `function_name(param1, param1);` and to declare a function we do it like this: `function_name(param1, param2) {}`

Comment: Re your question on the answer I just deleted: *"Ok, so does it mean that the function connect returns a function instead of a string/object."* Yes.

Comment: A very humble question your majesty, :) may I know why you deleted the answer?